# How make joi output all errors with path after json schema validation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

Consider the code:

```
const Joi = require('joi');
const joiAssert = require('joi-assert');

let json = {
  "myObject": {
    "myNestedField": {
      "deepOne": "myValue"
    }
  },
  "myArray": [
    {"field": 1},
    {"field": 2},
    {"field": 3}
  ]
};

joiAssert(json, Joi.object().required().keys({
  myObject: Joi.object().required().keys({
    myNestedField: Joi.object().required().keys({
      deepOne: Joi.string().required().valid("valid")
    }),
    myArray: Joi.array().items(
      Joi.object().keys({
        field: Joi.number().required().valid(8)
      })
    )
  })
}));
```

It fails with:

```
AssertionError: object: "deepOne" must be one of [valid]
    at Object.<anonymous> (joi-assert.js:17:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

It there a way to make something like?

```
myObject.myNestedField.deepOne -  must be one of [valid]
myArray does not contain value [8]
```

E.g. output all validation error with corresponding paths?

Comment: You can create your custom error messages by catching the errors from the Joi.validate(jsonObj, schema) result.

Comment: May be, but I wanted some automated solution :) Also I have just single exception with single error... So even if I catch the error it is unclear how make full message with all fields and errors. :(

Comment: You have the full path in array inside the error.details.. so maybe you can create something automated :)

Comment: Do you want to achieve that using `joi-assert` only?